# How to measure predictor contribution in Generalized Linear Mixed Model?

Tags: modeling, glmm, predictor, model-comparison

In GLM, there is explained deviance (D square) (Guisan and Zimmerman 2000). Contribution of each predictor in the best model can be compared using the explained deviance in the model excluding each predictors to that of the full model, and expressed as ΔD2.

GLMM has conditional R square (Nakagawa and Schielzeth 2013), but I do not know how to compare contribution of each predictor. When I try the same method as the GLM, I get negative contribution in delta marginal R square.